# Can I uninstall a SQL Server Standard edition instance without affecting an existing Express edition instance?

Tags: sql-server, uninstallation

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition installed as the default (unnamed) instance (`MSSQLSERVER`) that was installed for a vendor who then installed an Express edition *named instance* on the same VM, that they used instead of the Standard Edition.

The Express edition has since been upgraded to SQL Server 2014 Express.

Can I uninstall the 2008 R2 Standard edition instance without affecting the 2014 Express edition instance? If so, what is the best practice for doing so in this situation?

Comment: Each instance is completely separate to the others, yes.

Comment: That is correct. The 2008 R2 service and associated SQL Server Agent service are stopped at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your reply. I thought you were asking if they were separate. Upon rereading it I realize that it's the answer I was hoping for.